# Share Spring context between EARs

Tags: spring, security, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to share Spring Security context between 2 EAR projects.

They both have the same hierarchy :

```
- EjbImpl
- EjbClient
- WebApplication
```

I need to call **project A**'s ejb from **project B**'s webapp.

**Project A**'s EJBs use `SecurityContextHolder` to get and check the current user roles.

What I need is to propagate the security context from B to A (and vice versa) but I really don't know how...

**Current ideas**

1. CAS authentication which is a single sign in but it's too invasive.
2. Use HttpInvokerExporter/HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean but I think it's not optimal for a local call...
3. Merge 2 projects but I really want to avoid this... to keep projects exportable separatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I'm using the solution 2 temporarily.